# How to pass start and end date in Twilio call logs using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need to get the call logs from my twilio account.

I used following links

> https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC199564de248bcb4df3968fab5481bf8a/Calls.csv?PageSize=1000

Here I need to pass start and end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  You can like this 

  $StartTime = '2018-11-13';
  $username  = $value['accountSid'];
  $password = $value['authToken'];
  $url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'.$value['accountSid'].'/Calls.json?StartTime='.$StartTime.'T00%3A00%3A00Z';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    $decode = json_decode($server_output,TRUE);

It's working form me get all call logs from twilio.
```

OR you can use this code

```
  <?php
 // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
  require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
 use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$records = $client->usage->records->read(
array(
    "category" => "calls-inbound",
    "startDate" => "2012-09-01",
    "endDate" => "2012-09-30"
  )
 );

// Loop over the list of records and echo a property for each one
 foreach ($records as $record) {
  echo $record->price;
}
```